# How to write flexibleSearch query in hybris HAC for one too many relation?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

[image]This one doesn't work:
SELECT *FROM {User as u JOIN Address as a ON {u:a} = {a:pk}} .

Comment: Please don't use a picture of code. Copy and paste text into your question instead.

Answer (score 2):

As you see in the relation cardinality is on the owner as User.

so query should be like this

```
SELECT *FROM {User as u JOIN Address as a ON {u:pk} = {a:owner}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missed that qualifier is "owner" , usually by convention it is named as a type .
select {a.PK} from {customer as c join address as a on {c.pk}={a.owner}}

Answer (score 0):

Can try this:

```
 select * from {User as u JOIN Address as a on {u.pk}={a.owner}}
```

Comment: Same as top answer except instead of `:` you use `.`. Why?